# Ruby remove empty, nil arrays strings from array of strings

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this array of arrays:

```
["[]", "[\"https://somewebsite1.com\"]", "[\"https://somewebsite2.com\"]", "[]", "[]", "[]", "---\n- https://somewebsite3.com\n", "--- []\n", "---\n- https://somewebsite4.com\n", "--- []\n", "--- []\n", "---\n- https://somewebsite.com\n", "---\n- https://somewebsite5.com\n", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

How can I:
1- remove all the empty, nil element
2- have an array of string:

```
["https://somewebsite1.com", "https://somewebsite2.com", "https://somewebsite3.com", "https://somewebsite4.com", "https://somewebsite.com", "https://somewebsite5.com"]
```

`array.select &:present?` remove `nil`
then `array.delete_if {|i| i == '[]'}` remove `[]`
so I am left with :

```
["[\"https://somewebsite1.com\"]", "[\"https://somewebsite2.com\"]",  "---\n- https://somewebsite3.com\n", "--- []\n", "---\n- https://somewebsite4.com\n", "--- []\n", "--- []\n", "---\n- https://somewebsite.com\n", "---\n- https://somewebsite5.com\n"]
```

Comment: No, that's not array of arrays. That's array of strings, where strings contain what appears to be yaml code

Comment: A weird mix of YAML and JSON? Or is `[]` valid YAML, without the leading `---`?

Comment: @meagar: yes, [it appears to be valid yaml](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=%5B%22https%3A%2F%2Fsomewebsite1.com%22%5D&type=json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is a simple array of strings.

You can remove nil elements using `array.compact` or `array.reject(&:nil?)`

And to remove empty yaml entries you can use deserialization

`array.compact
  .reject { |i| YAML.parse(i).children.first.children.empty? }
  .map { |i| i.gsub('["', '').gsub('"]', '').gsub("---\n- ", '').strip }`

So the output would be you stated.

**Update:**

Another approach, without string manipulation

```
res = a.compact
deserialized = res.map { |i| YAML.parse(i) }
res = deserialized.reject { |i| i.children.first.children.empty? }
res.map { |i| i.children.first.children.first.value }
```

Comment: Much gsub, so string manipulation, wow. :) Why not use output of `YAML.parse` instead? Or, better, `YAML.load`?

Comment: It's fast and dirty solution. Yeah, working with deserialized YAML would be much better.

Comment: Just use `YAML.load`, it'll simplify code _substantially_. `my_array.compact.map(&YAML.method(:load)).reject(&:empty?).flatten`

Answer (score 1):

To just remove nil elements, you can use the `compact` method on an array.
To remove both nil and empty strings, you can use the `select` method:

```
my_array.select! { |element| element&.size.to_i > 0 }
```

To process the remaining strings, you'll need to iterate over each string and figure out whether it needs YAML parsing or not. The method you'll use to collect the results of that iteration is `map`:

```
my_array.map! { |element| clever_string_parsing_on(element) }
```

Comment: Have you tried your first snippet? It's not working.

Comment: My bad - I *had* tried it, but with too simple a test case; the bug didn't show up.  I've edited in a fix.  Good catch, and many thanks!